# EF6.1 newsequentialid with ability to set value manually

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm new to EF(v6.1). Trying to use Code-First approach.
I would like to have Id column to be generated on SQL server side (`newsequentialid()`), however with ability to override those values. 
My code:

```
[Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Which results in perfect SQL:

```
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newsequentialid())
```

However EF simply ignores any value I would set to `Id` property and pass null to SQL. Essentially follwing test wouldn't work:

```
MyContext context = new MyContext();
MyClass item = new MyClass();
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
item.Id = id;
context.MyTable.Add(item);
context.MyTable.Create();
context.SaveChanges();
Assert.AreEqual(item.Id, id);
```

What should I do to make my test work?

Comment: Just create a second `DbContext` subclass that maps "MyClass" (but under an alias name) to the same table, without `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. Use this class for the exceptional cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set manually your `Guid` `Id` property then remove `DatabaseGenerated` attribute:

```
[Key] 
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

If you configure your PK property as `Identity`, the value will be generated in your DB.Also, you don't need to mark this property as `Required`, PK properties are required by default.

Comment: I'd like it to be generated by db like 99.99% of all times, however I want ability to override that behaviour. Isn't there any way? In normal SQL (given the column configuration above) nothing prevents me from executing script below if I really need to:
`insert into [MyTable]
(Id)
values
('74C17675-6C85-4C79-9C0C-41E1FA4C059D')`

Comment: Well, you are going to need to disable that column as identity doing what I suggest, and using migration later to modify your db shema. Then you should be able to add that row with your specific value, and at the mark again that column as Identity and generate another migration to rollback that column as identity

Comment: Take a look this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Unfortunatelly that's not exaclty what I want. I never know when the user who's using my code would need to set Id explicitly. It seems my option should be generating sequantial id's on server side (as a constructor of class) - rather than SQL, which I don't really like.

Comment: My advice disable that property as Identity and generate a default Id in the constructor of your entity. This way you should be able to set that property with an specific value when you need